# On irreducible orientable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

The assumption on a $3$-manifold of being orientable and irreducible, and containing an embedded projective plane, automatically implies that the manifold is diffeormorphic to $\mathbb{RP^3}$?

I'm not asking for a proof of this, this is obviously not a trivial result. I think it may be a consequence of a strong theorem in 3-dimensional topology, like Alexander's or the Sphere Theorem, it's just that I can't find it.
Could you give me some reference, or any idea in this direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an oriented 3-manifold with an embedded $\Bbb{RP}^2$. The normal bundle can't be trivial lest the whole 3-manifold be non-orientable; so taking a tubular neighborhood you have a 3-manifold with $S^2$ boundary (the total space of the unit disc bundle of the tautological bundle); call this $M_1$. By the irreducibility hypothesis the boundary must bound a ball on the other side. So our manifold is diffeomorphic to $M_1$ capped off with a ball. But you can explicitly show that $\Bbb{RP}^3$ is $M_1$ capped off with a ball - so that must be our manifold.

This argument is similar in flavor to the proof that $S^2 \times S^1$ is the only oriented prime non-irreducible 3-manifold.

(If you assume that the embedded $\Bbb{RP}^2$ is 2-sided, you get the same result even without assuming orientability. If you don't, it's obviously not true, eg $\Bbb{RP}^2 \times S^1$.)

Comment: Thanks @MikeMiller! That is really helpful. Thumbs up!